# How to split my request which I am sending from one of the services in velocity apache using hyphen (-)?

Tags: soapui, velocity

I have data coming in from my backend service as `1234567-1`. I have to split this data using a hyphen(`-`) in Velocity Apache Request transformation and need to pass it in.

```
ABC = 1234567
DEF = 1
```

and using ABC and DEF I am again doing a request call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call all Java String methods on a string, and size() on arrays and lists:

```
#set($parts = $data.split('-'))
#if($parts.size() != 2)
  ## error handling
  ...
#else
  ## normal processing
  #set($ABC = $parts[0])
  #set($DEF = $parts[1])
  ...
#end
```